# Can the css template area span across multiple row and column?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

grid-template-areas: "";
Is it possible to span a particular div across multiple rows & columns?

[code link](https://codepen.io/aravisv/pen/yLKORav)

For example:

```
.container-3{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-area: 
    "m m m m h h h h h h h h "
    "m c c c c c c c c c c c"
    "m f f f f f f f f f f f";
    gap:10px;
    padding-bottom: 500px;
}

.header1{
    grid-area: h ;
}

.menu1{
    grid-area: m;
    background-color: orange;
}

.content1{
    grid-area: c;
}

.footer1{
    grid-area: f;
}
```